# Converting multiple namespaces XSD to Java

Tags: java, xml, maven, xsd, jaxb

When I needed convert XSD to java, I always was using JAXB. To automate XSD updates on java project `maven` comes in help with `jaxb2-maven-plugin`. Standard configuration in `pom.xml` for this conversation looks like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
      <extension>true</extension>
      <arguments>
        <argument>-Xfluent-api</argument>
      </arguments>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>generate-schema</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>xjc</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <sources>
            <source>xsd/xsd_location</source>
          </sources>
          <sourceType>xmlschema</sourceType>
          <xjbSources>
            <xjbSource>xsd/LocalDateTimeBinding.xjb</xjbSource>
          </xjbSources>
          <packageName>com.example.schema</packageName>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
</plugin>
```

Where under `xsd/xsd_location` I put my XSD files and `xsd/LocalDateTimeBinding.xjb` contains LocalDateTime adapter for JAVA 8+ to avoid joda.time. Sources was generated to java `target` folder under package name `com.example.schema`. Everything was working great with simple XSD. This time i have complex one, so don't know what to do. The issue is due multiple namespaces containing same types. XSD example looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<xsd:schema xmlns="http://mydaomain.com/BusinessObjects/Common/AdditionalInformationDataListType/V2" targetNamespace="http://example.com/BusinessObjects/Common/AdditionalInformationDataListType/V2" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns0="http://example.com/BusinessObjects/Common/AdditionalInformationDataType/V1" xmlns:ns1="http://example.com/BusinessObjects/Common/AdditionalInformationDataType/V2">
  <xsd:import namespace="http://example.com/BusinessObjects/Common/AdditionalInformationDataType/V1" schemaLocation="../../../../BusinessObjects/Common/AdditionalInformationDataType/V1/AdditionalInformationDataType.xsd"/>
  <xsd:import namespace="http://example.com/BusinessObjects/Common/AdditionalInformationDataType/V2" schemaLocation="../../../../BusinessObjects/Common/AdditionalInformationDataType/V2/AdditionalInformationDataType.xsd"/>
  <xsd:complexType name="AdditionalInformationDataListType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xsd:element name="additionalInformationDataV1" type="ns0:AdditionalInformationDataType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xsd:element name="additionalInformationDataV2" type="ns1:AdditionalInformationDataType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Issue is that

```
../../../../BusinessObjects/Common/AdditionalInformationDataType/V1/AdditionalInformationDataType.xsd
```

and

```
../../../../BusinessObjects/Common/AdditionalInformationDataType/V2/AdditionalInformationDataType.xsd
```

are in different folders, different version XSD types, under different namespace, but both have the same type name.

My current configuration tries to put them on the same package and I get error what file already exists. I can't change XSD (and I don't want to, because it contains over 100 files).

I was looking for some way to put different namespace sources under different packages but with no luck so far.

Comment: No answers in the question, please. I have rolled back/edited your question and removed the answer. Add the answer in the answer section only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you can fine-tune the package names for each namespace.

I would try two things:

1. Either remove "packageName" from plugin, or (better)
2. Define a package name for each namespace using Jaxb customization file

```xml
    <jxb:bindings version="1.0"
                   xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
                   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

        <!--
            Change since version 2.0 of the j-m-p:

            Note that the schemaLocation path must point to the XSD file
            relative to *this* file, rather than the basedir.
        -->
      <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="../xsd/address.xsd" node="//xsd:schema">
          <jxb:schemaBindings>
             <jxb:package name="com.example.myschema"/>
          </jxb:schemaBindings>
      </jxb:bindings>

    </jxb:bindings>
```

The example is taken from plugins [documentation](http://www.mojohaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/Documentation/v2.3.1/example_xjc_basic.htm) (scroll down to section 6 Using an XML Java Binding file)

Comment: Somehow i missed this part.. Looks kinda that i need, but full schema contains 3616 XSD files, so it will take a while.. Thinking to do bash script to generate bindings, and then pass them to addon. Will update on my progress later

Answer (score 0):

As Babis Routis suggested in answer, i ended up using jaxb bindings file. My schema contains lots of files, so i didn't want to do it manual.. To automate process i written sh script:

```
bfile=bindings.xjb
binding='\t<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="%s" node="//xsd:schema">\n\t\t<jxb:schemaBindings>\n\t\t\t<jxb:package name="%s"/>\n\t\t</jxb:schemaBindings>\n\t</jxb:bindings>\n'
echo '<jxb:bindings xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" version="2.1">' > ${bfile}
for fname in $(find . -name '*.xsd' -print)
do
    case $fname in
         *"/V1/"*) 
            printf "$binding" "$fname" "com.example.schema.v1" >> ${bfile}
            ;;
         *"/V2/"*) 
             printf "$binding" "$fname" "com.example.schema.v2" >> ${bfile}
             ;; 
        *) 
             printf "$binding" "$fname" "com.example.schema" >> ${bfile}
             ;;
     esac
done
echo "</jxb:bindings>" >> ${bfile}
```

It generates each version in different packages based on directory path, and if XSD don't have version - it goes to main package. To make it work need to remove `packageName` from `pom.xml` and add this to bindings configuration.